# how to import json file in mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb

While creating an application in which data is stored as a JSON file,
I need it to be imported into MongoDB.
I tried to use the following command but got the error --> `Failure parsing josn near: }`
my command is:

```bash
mongoimport -d mydb -c mydb --type json --file glossary.json --headerline
```

My file is located in `C:\mongodb\bin\glossary.json`.
Here is the content of my file:

```json
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your JSON seems to have only a single object. Format like `{..},{..}` is expected.

So, use `--jsonArray` option:

```
 mongoimport -d mydb -c mycollection --jsonArray < glossary.json
```

The other option is to format the source document as mongodb expects it to be. This will make loading much faster.

Comment: @user2511142 I used `--jsonArray` option, it worked for your file. Updated in answer.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the way to see imported json file's data ?

Comment: @user2511142 [open `mongo` shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/), run `use mydb`, then `db.mycollection.find().pretty()`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a large collection, `--jsonArray` takes a very long time to import. I was getting about 10 documents/second. If you have a properly formatted `.json` file you can just use `--file` instead. I'm getting about 6000 documents/second now.

Good thing I didn't settle for the first option!

Comment: what is the "properly formatted `.json` file"? Can you reference or show an example, please?

Comment: this has been quite a while, but I think I was just referencing something that is valid json - so maybe try pasting your json text somewhere like here: https://jsonlint.com/ to verify its correct

Comment: The file may need to be formatted with a single json object per line (as in, all of it on the same line, not spread over several lines).  I have also seen some comments that there can be no white space.  So this is well formatted:
{"foo":"bar"}
But this is not:
{ "foo" : "bat" }